How to resend webrequest via a firefox extension?
I am developing a FireFox addon. I want to make that every time a PUT web request with debug_source: "played_threshold_reached" in its JSON request body is sent, the extension sends it with the same headers and everything exactly equal 5 time more.
I tried the following code for background.js:
console.log("Background script loaded");

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
  const arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  async (details) => {
    if (details.method === "PUT") {
      try {
        const requestBody = JSON.parse(arrayBufferToString(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes));

        if (requestBody.debug_source === "played_threshold_reached") {
          console.log("Intercepted matching request!");

          const repeatRequest = async () => {
            const headers = {};
            details.requestHeaders.forEach(header => {
              headers[header.name] = header.value;
            });

            const response = await fetch(details.url, {
              method: "PUT",
              headers,
              body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
              mode: "cors",
              credentials: "same-origin"
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
              console.error("Failed to resend request:", response.statusText);
            }
          };

          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            console.log(`Sending request ${i + 1}`);
            await repeatRequest();
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error processing request:", error);
      }
    }
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["requestBody", "blocking", "extraHeaders", "requestHeaders"]
);

The Problem is, I dont even see the "Background script loaded" log at the beginning!
This is the manifest.json file:
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Request Repeater",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}

I ensured that I added
the extension correctly.

The title "How to resend webrequest via a firefox extension?" is a bit misleading. It should be something more like "webrequest handler extension doesn't load," since that's the actual question.
It's been a while since you asked the question, so maybe you already know the answer, but you said:

The Problem is, I dont even see the "Background script loaded" log at the beginning!

When I load your code as a temporary add-on, I do get "Background script loaded" logged to the console. Make sure you're looking at the right console. On about:debugging > This Firefox, "Inspect" your extension. That's the console where the background logs console messages.
Also, the extraInfoSpec parameter for addListener doesn't have valid "extraHeaders" and "requestHeaders" values. There should be an uncaught error if your code runs with those values. The error shows up in the console, too.
["requestBody", "blocking", "extraHeaders", "requestHeaders"]

should be just
["requestBody", "blocking"]

